# Sorting through a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a list that describes a hierarchy, as such:

`[obj1, obj2, [child1, child2, [gchild1, gchild2]] onemoreobject]`

Where, child1 (and others) are children of obj2, while gchild1 and 2 are children of child 2.

Each of this objects has attributes like `date`, for example, and I want to sort them according to such attributes. In regular list I would go like this:

`sorted(obj_list, key=attrgetter('date'))`

In this case, nonetheless that method wont work, since lists don't have `date` attribute... Even if it did, if its attribute would be different of its parent, then the hierarchical ordering would be broken. Is there a simple and elegant way to do this in python?

Comment: This looks like it would be a perfect dataset for a Tree Structure.

Comment: Can you provide desired output? Do you want to sort the list lexicographically while maintaining the hierarchy? i.e., `[obj2, obj1, [child1, child2, [gchild1, gchild2]] onemoreobject]` would sort to `[obj1, [child1, child2, [gchild1, gchild2]], obj2, onemoreobject]`?

Comment: The desired output, as said, would depend on a object attribute named `date`. Your example would be valid, if the dates would be arranged in such a way, but I, by no means, intended to sort according to the objects name.

So if `obj1.date` was march second and `obj2.date` was march first, this portion of the list should look like:

`[obj2, [child1, child2, [gchild1, gchild2]], obj1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put your key in the sort(key=None) functions and this will work.  I tested it with strings and it seems to work. I wasn't sure of the structure of onemoreobject.  This was sorted to the beginning with obj1 and obj2.  I thought that onemoreobject might represent a new hierarchy so I enclosed each hierarchy into a list to keep like objects together.

```
def embededsort(alist):
  islist = False
  temp = []
  for index, obj in enumerate(alist):
    if isinstance(obj,list):
      islist = True
      embededsort(obj)
      temp.append((index,obj))
  if islist:
    for lists in reversed(temp):
      del alist[lists[0]]
    alist.sort(key=None)
    for lists in temp:
      alist.append(lists[1])
  else:
    alist.sort(key=None)
  return alist

>>>l=[['obj2', 'obj1', ['child2', 'child1', ['gchild2', 'gchild1']]], ['obj22', 'obj21', ['child22', 'child21', ['gchild22', 'gchild21']]]]  
>>>print(embededsort(l))
[['obj1', 'obj2', ['child1', 'child2', ['gchild1', 'gchild2']]], ['obj21', 'obj22', ['child21', 'child22', ['gchild21', 'gchild22']]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of QuickSort algorithm using the polymorphism provided by Python. It should work for ints, floats, lists, nested lists, tuples and even dictionaries

```
def qsort(list):
    if not list: return []
    first   = list[0]
    lesser  = filter( lambda x: x <  first, list[1:] )
    greater = filter( lambda x: x >= first, list[1:] )
    return qsort(lesser) + [first] + qsort(greater)
```

Comment: Works on a flat list, but on my nested list still getting:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'date'`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers, as they gave me quite a few ideas, and new stuff to learn from. The final code, which seems to work looks like this. Not as shor and elegant as I imagined, but works:

```
def sort_by_date(element_list):
    last_item = None
    sorted_list = []
    for item in element_list:
        #if item is a list recurse and store it right below last item (parent)
        if type(item) == list:
            if last_comparisson:
                if last_comparisson == 'greater':
                    sorted_list.append(sort_by_date(item))
                else:
                    sorted_list.insert(1, sort_by_date(item))
        #if not a list check if it is greater or smaller then last comparisson
        else:
            if last_item == None or item.date > last_item:
                last_comparisson = 'greater'
                sorted_list.append(item)
            else:
                last_comparisson = 'smaller'
                sorted_list.insert(0, item)
            last_item = item.date
    return(sorted_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort all children of a node without taking into consideration those nodes which are not siblings, go for a tree structure:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, payload):
        self.payload = payload
        self.__children = []

    def __iadd__ (self, child):
        self.__children.append (child)
        return self

    def sort (self, attr):
        self.__children = sorted (self.__children, key = lambda x: getattr (x.payload, attr) )
        for child in self.__children: child.sort (attr)

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '{}: {}'.format (self.payload, self.__children)
```

Comment: I think this answer would trip up on this part of the question: "if its attribute would be different of its parent, then the hierarchical ordering would be broken".

Comment: I didn't understand this part of the question. Could you explain to me what it means.

Comment: Does he want to sort the children of each node according to an attribute without taking into consideration the rest of the nodes?

Comment: With the weird data structure the OP has, some of the elements in the list are objects, which are the nodes, and some are lists, containing the children of the nodes just before them in the main list. I think they want to sort just the nodes, and keep the children attached to those nodes.